# Calculating the number of combinations in a list expansion

Tags: combinations

How would you calculate the total unique combinations given a list of M elements padded with N additional elements (all the same) at any indexes within the list?

For example, say you have the list `m = [a, b, c]`, and you want to generate all combinations padded with elements `n = [z]`, this would generate 4 combinations, `[z, a, b, c]`, `[a, z, b, c]`, `[a, b, z, c]`, `[a, b, c, z]`.

For `m = [a, b, c, d]` and `n = [z, z]`, it becomes more complex, with the result having 15 unique combinations, like, `[z, z, a, b, c, d]`, `[z, a, z, b, c, d]`, etc.

I'm trying to write a formula, `f(m,n)`, that will return the total number of combinations, but I'm not sure how to handle the uniqueness factor. At first I thought it was simply `f(m,n) = (m+1)*n`. That predicts correctly for m=3,n=1 and m=4,n=1 but that fails to predict for m=4 and n=2, which results in 15 unique combinations.

So then I thought it was a summation of these functions, like:

```
f(m,n) = sum((m+1)*(n-i) for i in range(n))
```

This correctly predicts 15 for the inputs of m=4,n=2, but again fails for m=4,n=3, which is 35.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not getting it what actually you want that only z to be inserted into the fixed sequence of a,b,c,d or a,b,c,d order can also change.can both z can be together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assuming the order of the $m$ distinguishable elements is fixed, the function $f$ can be written as
  $$
  f(m,n)
  =
  {\small{\binom{m+n}{n}}}
  =
  \frac{(m+n)!}{m!{\,\cdot\,}n!}
  =
  \frac{\displaystyle{{\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(m+n-k)}}}{m!}
  =
  \frac{\displaystyle{{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(m+n-k)}}}{n!}
  $$
  Explanation: Choose the locations of the $n$ indistinguishable "other" elements:$\;{\large{\binom{m+n}{n}}}\;$ choices.

  For example: $f(4,2)={\large{\binom{6}{2}}}=15$, and $f(4,3)={\large{\binom{7}{3}}}=35$.

  If the order of the $m$ distinguishable elements is allowed to vary, the function $f$ can be written as
  $$
  f(m,n)
  =
  {\small{\binom{m+n}{n}}}{\cdot\,}m!
  =
  \frac{(m+n)!}{n!}
  =
  \prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(m+n-k)
  $$
  Explanation:

  - Choose the locations of the $n$ indistinguishable "other" elements:$\;{\large{\binom{m+n}{n}}}\;$ choices.

    Choose the order of the $m$ distinguishable elements:$\;m!\;$choices.

Comment: Thank you. The first is what I was looking for.